# Is there any way I can get all the chat messages I had with someone on Telegram using the API?

Tags: telegram

Okay, so I had a chat with someone on Telegram and I want all the chat messages so I can do some analysis of the messages and make some interesting visuals. Any way to get all the chat? I looked it up but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [messages.getHistory](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getHistory) method? The example of using it can be found in [kotlogram](https://github.com/badoualy/kotlogram) project in [SampleGetHistory.java](https://github.com/badoualy/kotlogram/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/github/badoualy/telegram/sample/SampleGetHistory.java).